# How to get only html contents from the DOM after removing angularjs code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have created a page with AngularJS, After it is getting rendered I want only the HTML contents not the angular attributes like ng-app, ng-controller etc.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController" id="001" class="some-class ng-scope">
```

In this div there is angular attribute **ng-controller** I want only this code:

```
<div id="001" class="some-class ng-scope">
```

Likewise there may be many attributes of AngularJs in the page. I want to remove all of this and get plain html. Can any one suggest how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Surely, it is a easy task.

If u include [AngularJS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) in your page, then after the page being loaded, it automatically converts the code (with angular tags) to plain HTML code. So after the page being loaded, it is a complete HTML page.

Then if u can use any kind of JS (Plain JS or any library like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) etc.) for extracting the DOM element.

One example is given here-

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Hope u have your answer.

---

**Update-**

U can inspect any page's element's like this-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnWL2d9bGPk

Comment: Yes, the page has html code but it still has angular attributes. I want only plain HTML code without angular code

Comment: Please inspect the element, u will see